# is there an opposite to system.out.println? (java)

Tags: java

Is there a line of code that will delete the last line printed? such that:

```
system.out.println("random text");

system.out.println("hello");

[some function]("hello");
```

will print: random text

Comment: No. There is not.

Comment: Console support in Java is very, very basic. If you want something more complex, then you need to look toward an external API, like Curses for example

Comment: thanks all!, how do I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already printed line, Java cannot erase them.
Using 'System.out.print()', you can try like this:

```
System.out.print("\r" + text);
```

\r will erase text on current line.
In IDE such as eclipse, it will be printed in new line. Try in command prompt.

Comment: I think this is specific to the OS, how \r is handled.

Comment: In Windows it worked, I think it will be same because Java is WORE(write once test everywhere) language. I'm not sure.

Comment: @dhkim0800 It's environment specific.  The special characters are handled by the console, not Java.  You prove this yourself in your own answer: it doesn't work in the eclipse console.

Comment: I also think you're right. But I think it'll work on most environments.